# Verify APNS server certificate is valid or not, in PHP

Tags: php, certificate, apple-push-notifications

How to verify the APNS server certificate is valid or not, in PHP ?

APNS certificate is concatenation of APNS Push Certificate (from Apple) and a Private Key in PKCS12 format. Given that I have the password of the Private Key, can I obtain the information from the certificate (such as Expiry Date)?

I attempted :

```
// to read the APNS certificate content
$results = array();
$is_success = openssl_pkcs12_read(file_get_contents($cert_path), $results, $password);
// then $results will contain certificate information
```

But how to separate APNS Push Certificate from the Private Key?